# Quick UI Design in Silverlight 4/ VS2010

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am looking for some advice on how to quickly create UI for Silverlight pages. I come from WinForms/WebForms background and as a developer, i could quickly place some controls and get going with coding. I find that it takes much longer to do this is Silverlight.

Looking for some ideas.

Comment: Use expression blend if you can, it speeds things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properly learn XAML, sorry. [This](http://www.apress.com/9781430272076) book is pretty good, it will tell you everything from XAML to WCF RIA Services to access your data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I highly recommend this book too (disclosure: I'm the author :). Getting up to speed with XAML can take some time, but once you get familiar with it you can actually work really fast. Stick with it, and buy a good book to help you :).